# Java programming language online tests

Tags: java, testing

Does anyone know if a popular online testing quiz that will work sort of as certification that people know how to program in a certain language?

To clarify what I am looking for is for some sort of free online certification, or a community site that will serve as such... basically something that employers will recognize to be as valid as a SCJP

Comment: Please read [this](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/extra/certification/index.html)

Comment: Why is this tagged homework? It's a simple question about certifications. Granted it may not show much research, and may not be posted in the right place.

Comment: Try these [Java Tests](http://www.codelect.net)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://knowledgeblackbelt.com/

Comment: Yes that is what I was looking for... but there seems to be little else just J2SE and J2EE, also some of the questions are a bit missleading. But thanks for the link. Do you know any more similar sites?

Answer (score 1):

Sun certification and Brainbench certification if you are looking for professional certification. If you just want to practice there are many free mock exams online (search for "j2se mock exams" in Google).

Answer (score 1):

Few sample quizzes for "Sun Certified Java Programmer" are available at http://www.gocertify.com/quizzes/#java and for "Oracle Certified Professional Java Programmer" at http://www.jmerge.com/sun/180-sun-certified-java-programmer-se-6-sample-questions.html

There is a plenty of online sample quizzes are available, search at Google.....